# OpenAI API error: Why do I still get the "module 'openai' has no attribute 'ChatCompletion'" error after I upgraded the OpenAI package and Python?

Tags: openai-api, chatgpt-api

I am getting the following error: `module 'openai' has no attribute 'ChatCompletion'`

I checked the other posts. They are all saying to upgrade the OpenAI Python package or upgrade Python. I did both but didn't fix it.

Python: `3.11.3`

OpenAI Python package: `0.27.7`

```
import openai
import os
openai.api_key = ""
prompt = f"""
write a short story about a person who is going to a party.
"""

response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant"},
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
    ],
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=2024,
    top_p=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0,
)

print(response["choices"][0]["message"]["content"])  # type: ignore
```

Comment: Can you do a pip freeze and check the openai version that is installed ?

Comment: Your code works with `openai==v0.28.1`

Answer (score 2):

**Don't name the file `openai.py`.**

You said you upgraded both the OpenAI Python package and Python, but the error persists.

One common mistake people make is naming the file `openai.py`. It'll cause the `module 'openai' has no attribute 'ChatCompletion'` error even though you upgraded everything.

Answer (score 0):

Either you install version 0.28.1, or do this to fix the code.

```
import openai
from openai import OpenAI
import os
os.environ["OPENAI_API_KEY"] = ""
client = OpenAI()

prompt = f"""
write a short story about a person who is going to a party.
"""

response = client.chat.completions.create(
    model="gpt-3.5-turbo",
    messages=[
        {"role": "system", "content": "You are a helpful assistant"},
        {"role": "user", "content": prompt},
    ],
    temperature=0,
    max_tokens=2024,
    top_p=1,
    frequency_penalty=0,
    presence_penalty=0,
)

print(response.choices[0].message.content)  # type: ignore
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?